# Adding one or two Vietnamese words in lualatex

Tags: luatex, babel, unicode, languages

I'm using lualatex and I just need to have a couple Vietnamese workds. I'd like to be able to do the special characters like /^a  but some of the letters have diacritics above and below, such as: ậ

I would like to avoid copying and pasting. I tried to use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` and I must be doing it wrong. According to another recommendation, I included:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,vietnamese]{babel}
```

Been bustng my head on this for a while. Any suggestions?

Comment: You don't need `fontenc` nor `inputenc`, LuaLaTeX defaults to Unicode characters.

Comment: `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T5,T1]{fontenc} ` is for pdflatex. With lualatex you only need a font.

Comment: So, in lualatex, how to add unicode characters for special characters? I don't have a VN keyboard, and I don't want to copy and paste ('cause then I don't learn nothing, and I'm trying to get better at this stuff).

Comment: @mmij You can type ậ or `\Uchar"1EAD` or `^^^^1ead`  or `\^{\d{a}}` for example

Comment: You can use any input method to type Unicode in your editor, and save as UTF-8. For example, a character map.

Comment: With `\usepackage[english,vietnamese]{babel}` you are setting Vietnamese as the main language (because it's the last one). I presume you want `\usepackage[vietnamese,english]{babel}`.

Answer (score 2):

`inputenc` and `fontenc` should not be used with luatex, and if it is just one or two inserted words you probably don't need any particular language support at all. The default Latin Modern already supports ậ.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

ậ = \^{\d{a}} = ^^^^1ead 

\end{document}
```

As shown here you can enter the character directly or via classic TeX accent commands or by Unicode hex value. Note the middle form using nested classic accent commands works in this case but isn't recommended and relies on good support for Unicode combining characters in the font being used.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I did a copy and paste as an earlier test, but I would like to avoid that and input what I need as unicode.

Edit: ^^^^1EAD  worked. Thanks.   Strangely, \CHAR"1EAD deleted the character before it and also didn't show U+1EAD.

Where did you find the information on the 4^ command? I could use a better resource, I think.

Comment: @mmij you were trying `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` which would allow `ậ` to be used in pdftex, so I assumed this was the input you wanted. You could use (for example)  `\^{\d{a}}` if you prefer.

Comment: @mmij what do you mean by "input what I want as Unicode"? `ậ` _is_ Unicode. If you mean that you want touse the hex code point you can use `^^^^1ead`

Comment: I have been hunting for these commands for over two hours. Thank you. Please, where is the information for how to use/make commands like: \^{\d{a}}

Yes, you are correct about my mistake with the name. Sorry, new baby, no sleep, too much work. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: `\^` and `\d` are standard latex accent commands that shoudl be in any latex tutorial. Actually I'd avoid using doubled ones in general (relies on the font having support for the Unicode combining accents) but it's OK here.

Comment: Note that `ậ` or `^^^^1ead` is preferrable to `\^{\d{a}}` (or `\d{\^{a}}`) because the latter composes the glyph from `ȧ`+`^` (or `â`+`̣`) which may not look good depending on the font.  With `a` the output is identical, but try `ệ` vs `\^{\d{e}}` (use `ệ{\color{red}\llap{\^{\d{e}}}}` to see the difference clearly)

Comment: Thank you everyone. These work, and now I also have some leads to follow. The only other answers I was finding were about installing extra packages or VNTeX.

Comment: See https://www.learnlatex.org/vi/